# This opencv program is for loading different images from a folder at the same time, but it reads only one image

Tags: c++, opencv

This OpenCV program is for loading different images from a folder at the same time. But it reads only one image, please help me to find what is happening here..

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <dirent.h>
    #include<cv.h>
    #include<highgui.h>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
       struct dirent *dirpent;
       DIR *dirp;
       IplImage* image;
       if(argc!=2)
       {
       printf("Cant continue with the program\n");
       return 0;
       }
       dirp= opendir(argv[1]);
       if(dirp==NULL)
            {
                cout<<"error"<<endl;
            }
           while(dirpent=readdir(dirp))
           {    
            char *b=dirpent->d_name;
             if(b[0]=='.')
              {

              }
            else
             {
                image=(IplImage*)cvLoadImage(dirpent->d_name);
                cvNamedWindow("output");
                cvShowImage("output",image);
                cvWaitKey(0);
                cvReleaseImage(&image);
                cvDestroyWindow("output");  
            }        
          }
 closedir(dirp);

   return 0;

   }
```

Comment: At the same time? You mean load them one-by-one?

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the following lines out of (after) the `while`-scope:

```
cvReleaseImage(&image);
cvDestroyWindow("output");
```

And move the following line before the `while`-scope as you don't need create the window each time.

```
cvNamedWindow("output");
```